# outlook 2013 can't set td width

Tags: html, css, outlook

I'm working on html mail, but the width of last column is too small, my code is :

```html
<td width='250' style="width: 250px !important;">
    开发               
</td>
```

and result is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7fwy.png)
but when the word change to English not Chinese, the width works well:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FCZG.png),
and when using web outlook it works well, but when use outlook client the width is too small.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the width and height also in your Table.

```
   <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="250" height="80">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="80" width="250">
        </td>
       </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: @emmaxia can you post the full code of your table? might be helpfull

Comment: The problem is solved,  set ```style="white-space:nowrap;"```